# fileupload with jquery ui progressbar

Tags: jquery, user-interface, progress-bar, jcrop

I am using jCrop and i would like to add a progress bar for the image upload, 
How can make the jquery ui progressbar get the image bytes loaded?

Comment: I believe this thread is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367539/want-to-display-progress-bar-while-uploading-file-using-jquery-ui-progress-bar/8371046#8371046

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great [Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and here is the [Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jquery Uploader Plugin](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php)